# How to print special Latin characters in Markdown pdfs

Tags: r-markdown

I need to knit my Markdown script into a pdf file, but when knitted, the pdf file does not show special Latin characters, such as those used in the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA).

````
---
title: "MarkdownIPA"
date: '2022-07-06'
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
`Print IPA`
```{r}
'[aɪ.pʰiː.ɛɪ]'
```
````

Which rends:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a font that supports those glyphs. A (IMHO) rather nice one is *Source Sans Pro* and the monospace variant *Source Code Pro*.

To use *Source Code Pro*, you can add the respective LaTeX code directly:

```yaml
---
title: "MarkdownIPA"
date: '2022-07-06'
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{sourcecodepro}
---
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of the resulting PDF file, showing IPA characters set in a monospace font]

The `sourcecodepro` package is likely already installed; otherwise you'd have to install it first.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I installe the sourcecodepro package?